# How do you deduce that matrices are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

i wanted to ask for a clarification.

I was looking around in my linear algebra text when i reached this justification:

> Considered two coloumn vectors $X$ and $Y$, and assume
> $$X ^tC Y = X^t C^t Y$$
> for every $X,Y \in V$, with $V$ an $n$-dimensional vectorial space, with $X^t, Y^t$ being the transposed of $ X, Y$.

My book says that because of this is valid for every $X,Y$, we can deduce:
$$ C^t = C$$

Now, it is intuitively true, but i was wondering if ,maybe the general sum (it's a bilinear form) could equals without needing $C^t = C$.
I've seen this type of justification also in other theorems, but i want to know if there is a way to prove it formally, beacuse i'm not satisfied.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See what happens if $X=e_i$ and $Y=e_j$ ($i$-th and $j$-th standard basis vectors of $V$).

Comment: What does this have to do with the “null” in the title?

Comment: The transpose of a linear transformation doesn’t make sense over a general vector space. But it does make sense if the vector space is given an inner product.

Comment: Sorry, language translations

Answer (score 2):

since these are column vectors, evidently $V=\mathbb F^n$

select $n$ linearly independent vectors $\mathbf x_k$ and $n$ linearly independent $\mathbf y_k$ (if you like you can set $\mathbf y_k:=\mathbf x_k$)

Then for $k,j \in \big\{1,2,...,n\big\}$
$\mathbf x_k^T C\mathbf y_j=\mathbf x_k^T C^T\mathbf y_j$
$\implies\mathbf x_k^T\big( C-C^T\big)\mathbf y_j = \mathbf 0$
$\implies \mathbf X^T\big( C-C^T\big)\mathbf Y = \mathbf 0$
where $\mathbf X$ and $\mathbf Y$ have column $j$ given by $\mathbf x_j$ and $\mathbf y_j$ respectively.  But $\mathbf X$ and $\mathbf Y$ are invertible,
$\implies \big( C-C^T\big) = \mathbf 0$
$\implies C=C^T$

Answer (score 1):

Setting $A = C-C^t$ you have $X^tAY=0$ for all $X,Y$. Let $e_j$ denote the $j$-th standard basis vector. The $(i,j)$-th entry of $A$ can be expressed as $e_i^tAe_j$. But this is zero, hence $A=0$, i.e., $C^t = C$.